# How to flush content to bottom in container, when neither container nor content height are known?

Tags: css

I have this situation: http://liveweave.com/roBPrb . Here is the source:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    This should be always at<br/>
    the bottom, the container<br/>
    should grow with the texts size.
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (ignore the colors):

```
.container {
  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
}
```

I want two things:

- The container should increase its size with its content.
- The content should always be at the bottom of the container.

How do I do that? It should be compatible with IE >= 9 and somewhat modern versions of other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution myself, the trick is to use `display: flex;`. Here is the solution: http://liveweave.com/aMpV8V.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    This should be always at<br/>
    the bottom, the container<br/>
    should grow with the texts size.
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;

  min-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.content {
  width:  100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

According to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) this *almost* fulfills my requirements: IE 9 support is missing, but everybody else supports it.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 120px;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    This should be always at<br/>
    the bottom, the container<br/>
    should grow with the texts size.<br />
    should grow with the texts size.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not fulfill my first requirement: The container should grow with its content. Since the content is absolutely positioned, the container will collaps (here: always have its min-height).

Comment: Then remove min-height.

Comment: max-height is set which works perfectly. just set height: auto;

Comment: I cannot open the site due to low internet connection. You can tell me what problem you're having....

Comment: The container does not grow with the content div. So if you add more text, the content will grow out of the container, at the top. But I'd like the container to grow with its content.

Comment: That would not work, because the child (content) has `display: absolute`, so it has no influence over the height of the parent whatsoever. Setting `overflow: hidden` is what I'd like to avoid, since I want all content to be visible and without scrollbar.

Comment: No, now the problem is that the content is not always at the bottom of the container, when I set a `min-height` that is bigger than the height the content has.

Comment: If you need min-height, use absolute position check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.container {
  max-height:100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  height:auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:  0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Note that the parent container must have a relative position in order for the absolute positioning of the child to work. I hope you found what you were looking for.

Comment: This does not fulfill my first requirement: The container should grow with its content. Since the content is absolutely positioned, the container will collaps (here: always have its min-height).

Comment: @Jost I've edited the answer to include the max height attribute and auto height. With these I think you'll get what you're looking for. Here's a link: http://liveweave.com/4pHygQ

Comment: That does not work, because the container does not grow with its contents: http://liveweave.com/Bfkxro